# Are questions about the stances (political/religious) of specific politicians or political appointees on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

For example, I have heard rumors that Mike Pence has association with churches and organizations that subscribe to Dominionism Theology. Is a question to in/validate these rumors on topic here?  If so, the follow-up question of which flavor of Dominionism (if the initial claim is substantiated) he is associated with on-topic?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, questions about the political positions of notable politicians are on-topic. But please try to focus on their actual position according to their own statements and actions. Do not fall for the [guilt by association](http://www.fallacyfiles.org/guiltbya.html) fallacy.

Religious believes not so much, unless they demonstrably affect their politics.

By the way: There is also [Skeptics Stackexchange](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/), which specializes on confirming or debunking claims. But keep in mind that [questions over there need to follow formal criteria](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/faq-welcome-to-new-users). For example, questions must refer to a specific claim made by a notable source.